# Slow compilation speed for "const unordered_map" as global variable

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, unordered-map, hpc

I am experiencing really slow compilation time, probably due to the existence of a global variable of the kind `std::unordered_map`. Below you can find the lines of code, which are located in a file called `correspondance.h`

```
    using Entry_t = std::tuple<Cfptr_t, short int, short int>;
    ...
    #include "map_content.h"
        inline const std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl{MAP_CONTENT};
    #undef MAP_CONTENT
```

and, in `map_content.h` there is the content of the map:

```
     #define MAP_CONTENT \
    { {EMPTYCHAR+corr::su_R,ANTICHAR,EMPTYCHAR+corr::sd_L,EMPTYCHAR+corr::A,EMPTYCHAR+corr::W},{    &mssm2to2::sumSqAmpl_su_R_anti_sd_L_to_A_W, 9,2}},\
    { {EMPTYCHAR+corr::su_L,ANTICHAR,EMPTYCHAR+corr::sd_R,EMPTYCHAR+corr::A,EMPTYCHAR+corr::W},{  &mssm2to2::sumSqAmpl_su_L_anti_sd_R_to_A_W, 9,2}},\
    ...
```

it goes on like this for about 3500 lines.
Note that

1. `Cfptr_t` is a function pointer
2. `EMPTYCHAR` and all the variables of the type `corr::something` are integers, so they define the key value string

The problem I encounter is that the makefile takes 10 minutes for each file that includes `correspondace.h`, since indeed there are so many lines of code to process.

As you may have understood, this map is needed to allow the user to access functions without knowing their names, but just with a string. For this reason I cannot at the moment eliminate this feature, since it's fundamental.

As far as I could do, I tried to include this file in as few files as possible. Anyways, it is inevitable to include it in every file that will generate the executable, so, overall, this forces me to wait a long time each time I have to debug something.

If you have any suggestion on how to speed up compilation keeping this feature, it would be really helpful for me :)

Comment: Do you need to initialize it in the header file? You could declare it there and define + initialize in .cpp file which would need to read the map_contant.h file only once?

Comment: Are you aware that with `inline`, each translation unit that includes this header will have its own copy of the map? Moving definition to .cpp file would make it initialized only once. And with some smarter build system like CMake, compiler won't rebuild it everytime, only when it changes (although it still needs to be linked every time you change other files, but that shouldn't have this much of impact).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen with inline, there is only one copy, but it still needs to be compiled for each TU. The copies are merged at the link stage.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Oh, I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @Kaldrr thanks for your comment, I'll try it out now !

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, as @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m pointed out, with `inline` I get it initialised only once. Moreover, the compiler gave me errors of multiple variables with the same name, of I didn't use that keyword :)

Comment: *"I tried to include this file in as few files as possible."* -- Good plan. Your goal should be one file. That is as few as possible. -- *"Anyways, it is inevitable to include it in every file that will generate the executable"* -- I don't believe that. Can you write out a convincing argument why this should be the case (i.e. why the *defintion* needs to be everywhere)? Inconvenient assumptions like this are prime candidates for [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Don't just accept that something cannot be done; force yourself to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#include "map_content.h"
inline const std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl{MAP_CONTENT};
#undef MAP_CONTENT
```

to

```
extern const std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl;
```

and in a new `.cpp` file:

```
#include "correspondance.h"
#include "map_content.h"
const std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl{MAP_CONTENT};
#undef MAP_CONTENT
```

This will cause only one definition of the map to be emitted (in contrast to `inline` which will emit it in every translation unit odr-using it).

It is safe as long as the map isn't used during the construction of another static storage duration object before `main` is entered. If that is required, it would be preferable to make the map a local static variable in a function returning it by-reference to be used by callers. This would avoid the "static initialization order fiasco".

---

It might also help to make a function to initialize the map with an `insert` statement for each entry instead of doing it all in the initializer, i.e. have a function `initSquaredampl` returning a `std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t>` by-value and then:

```
auto initSquaredampl() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl;
    // Insert items one-by-one
    return squaredampl;
}

const std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl = initSquaredampl();
```

This *may* help, because a compiler might not be optimized for compilation of very long expressions or initializers. However, they may also have trouble with very long functions.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank @Kaldrr and @user17732522 for the nice insights. I solved my problem in the following way. In `correspondance.h` I just put:

```
inline std::unordered_map<std::string, Entry_t> squaredampl;
```

i.e. a simple initialisation of the empty map.
Then, I created a new header `init_map.h` with the following lines:

```
#include "correspondance.h"

int Initialise();
```

and, of course, a correspondant `initialise_map.cpp` file with the definition of the function

```
#include "initialise_map.h"

int Initialise()
{
  if (!corr::squaredampl.empty()) return 0;
  corr::squaredampl.reserve(3500);
  corr::squaredampl = {
#include "map_content_body.h"
  };
  return 0;
}
```

where `map_content_body.h` are the lines of the content of the map. In this way:

1. The code for the map is in only one file
2. I avoided defining a macro and copying it
3. Once that I have the object file `initialise_map.o`, all the .cpp files that will generate the executable will not contain the code, but the function will be there in linking phase

As a result, unless I remove `initialise_map.o` or I update `initialise_map.cpp`, my code compiles at a normal speed, as it should be.

Of course, I took care of having a `#pragma once` or similar in each header file to avoid useless code copies.

Many thanks also to @JaMiT for the encouraging words :)

EDIT : As I was suggested in the comments, I eventually implemented the solution by @user17732522. In this way I don't have to call a function each time to do the initialisation.

Comment: That's not really what I meant. This change will require you to call `Initialise` everywhere the map might be used. That's not necessary with the `extern` approach I described. Also `reserve` is pointless, since you are replacing the object's contents with a temporary one's.

Comment: The `extern` approach only doesn't work if you use the map during initialization of another static storage duration object before `main` is entered. In that case it would be better to make the variable a `static` local variable inside `Initialise` and have it return a reference to the map.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'll try it out and I'll edit or delete my answer. In fact, not having to call the Initialise() each time is really handy.